# How to surpass Construct's Hardness with no heavy-hitter at low level?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, tactics, constructs

In Pathfinder 2E there are enemies like the [Animated Armor](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=19), constructs with the defensive ability "Construct Armor" which reduces all incoming damage by an amount equal to the listed Hardness value. Is a party with no heavy-hitter (fighters, barbarians) just supposed to hope for a critical hit or maybe chip damage the creature until it breaks? Or are there other ways to damage the creature?

Comment: Do you have a specific party in mind? If so, could you expand on their class/concepts and level(s) you expect them to fight one or more constructs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Any party should have the tools to fight one of these

It may take a couple Recall Knowledge checks and the GM providing information valuable to *that party*, but you'll note that Animated Armor and many other constructs that are not golems don't have immunity to magic nor critical hits (in fact, a critical hit reduces Animated Armor and some others' AC).

With a +3 Reflex save against level 2 DC's (about 18), the creature should fail about 70% of its rolls and critically fails 20%. Even Cantrip criticals at level 1-2 usually overcome 9 damage. Knowing that the creature's Reflex save ("ability to get out of area effects") is abysmal would be good information for a GM to give a group that are primarily spellcasters as well as the fact that its AC is similarly bad once it has been critically attacked once or loses half its health. Using Reflex Save spells, such as [Electric Arc](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=97), and breaking its armor for other attacks can easily whittle the creature down.

Other classes have ways that would allow them to damage this as well. Rogues' sneak attack is effective against them, as are Swashbucklers' Confident Finisher. Rangers' [Hunted Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=492) for ranged and [Twin Takedown](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=494) for melee allow them to total two attacks worth of damage against the Hardness.

Some classes may struggle to hit this threshold, but if the entire party is constructed in such a way it may be time to [address party balance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/183540/28326). Illusion and Enchantment may be fun on occasion, but you can't rely on them for (most) full adventures...

Comment: Gaining panache for even a Swashbuckler should be fairly trivial; Tumble Through is against Reflex DC. Even if somehow you have a +0 Dex bonus as a level 1 Swashbuckler, you have a 50% chance of succeeding at it. More likely you'll have to roll under a 6 to *not* get Panache. Overall, this is a nit pick to an otherwise accurate and excellent answer; +1.

Comment: Heh I honestly forgot about Tumble Through when I wrote that (which of course I don't when I *play a SwB on Wednesdays*) Thanks for keeping me from further embarrassment

Answer (score 6):

### You have more options than you think

A smashy-type works, as you note. And a sufficiently high-strength cleric doubles as a smashy-type.

Even if you're lacking those, a rogue-type with sneak attack will do the trick (the construct has no listed immunity to sneak attack; Pathfinder doesn't make undead and constructs immune by default like some editions of D&D); a 2d6 + Dex attack is enough to exceed the hardness on most hits.

If you have none of those? Well, this is what happens when you have a weird party balance; D&D-like games typically assume at least one warrior-type in the party, and having no one who even vaguely fills that niche is going to cause problems in many situations.